# This Binding within an apollo query

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I am trying to work a function from a clicked div that is rendered from an Apollo Query. I am having a binding problem where react is saying "this is undefined" My guess is because it is nested inside the Query component and passed to it as a prop  it is thinking that this is the Query which is the parent of SimpleNavButton?

I need it to go up to  Coinbase and call the next function. How would I declare this correctly?

```
class Coinbase extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  } 

  next() {
    prompt("Next");
  }

  prev() {
    prompt("Previous");
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <Query
        query={gql`
          {
            rates(currency: "USD") {
              currency
              rate
              name
            }
          }
        `}
      >
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
          if (error) return <p>Error...</p>;
          var count = 0;

          return data.rates.map(function({ currency, rate, name }) {
            count = count + 1;                         
            if(count === 1) {       
              return(
                <div key={count} className='card'>
                  <div>
                  <h1>({`${currency}`})</h1>
                  <h3>{`${name}`}</h3>
                  <h3>$1 usd = ${` ${rate}`} </h3>
                </div>
                <div className='nav-button-container'>
                  <SimpleNavButton onClick={this.prev().bind(this)}>&laquo;</SimpleNavButton>
                  <SimpleNavButton>&raquo;</SimpleNavButton>
                </div>
               </div>  
             )    
           } else {
             return(null)
           }
         });  
       }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're calling this.prev() which will return undefined. 
You want to bind the function and not call it.

Change this

**this.prev().bind(this)**

to

**this.prev.bind(this)**

Another way you could write the code is to use arrow functions for your action handlers to help bind them to the class. Which I highly recommend.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
class Coinbase extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  } 

  next = () => {
    prompt("Next");
  }

  prev = () => {
    prompt("Previous");
  } 

  render() {
    ...
    <SimpleNavButton onClick={this.prev}>&laquo;</SimpleNavButton>
```